# JavaFX 2.2 - Hiding percentage of a progressIndicator within a ListCell

Tags: css, javafx-2

I have a ListCell in which I display progress information of a file download by ProgressIndicator.

My problem is with removing the percentage information displayed below the indicator. As stated [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2331635), I included a rule in my css as following:

```
.customProgressIndicator .percentage{
    visibility: hidden;
    -fx-text-background-color: red;
}
```

The `-fx-text-background-color: red` part is just to be sure that our css is applied to the node.

The problem is, I make a call like `indicator.setProgress(progress)`, the percentage becomes visible (in red), and when I hover the cursor over the indicator, it becomes invisible again. Again at the end, "Done" text becomes visible at the bottom upon the call `indicator.setProgress(1.0)`, and again becomes invisible after a hover.

It might be related with `ListView` because; after hovering and causing it to become invisible, if I remove an item from the `List` and cause an `updateItem` on `ListCell`, it becomes again visible.

I have tried a workaround as:

```
    Text text = (Text)indicator.lookup(".percentage");
    if ( text != null )
    {
        text.setText("");
    }
```

But `text` is **sometimes** null, sometimes not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notes:

1) I read the post you linked and the OP implicitly confirms the `visibility: hidden;` is worked for him/her. But I have tested the same code and it is not working. Maybe due to version differences. I don't know.

2) `-fx-text-background-color` is not a CSS property. It is a predefined color in a caspian.css. So changing it you are implicitly changing the color of percentage label, defined as default in

```
.progress-indicator .percentage {
    -fx-font-size: 0.916667em; /* 11pt - 1 less than the default font */
    -fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

of caspian.css. (Note the `-fx-text-background-color` above)

3) Finally, the effect you want can be done through

```
.customProgressIndicator .percentage {
    -fx-fill: null;
}
```

P.S. I have not tested a progress indicator inside a listview.